# Changing themes using highcharts-angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm trying to change the Highcharts theme using the `highcharts-angular` package.  I have tried adding the theme to the `scripts` section of `angular.json` configuration but this does not work.  I really dont want to have to copy/paste the entire theme and manually inject it into the `Highcharts` object as per this page: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes.

Has anyone been able to nicely change themes using `highcharts-angular`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @KacperMadej for this solution on [github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular/issues/89).

To load a theme simply add the following somewhere in the project:

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/themes/dark-blue')(Highcharts);
```

Comment: Can also use ```import * as theme from 'highcharts/themes/dark-unica';

theme(Highcharts);``` if you dont want to use require

Comment: Thanks for the answers, @gatapia and @el-davo. In the current version of Highcharts, the theme factory is now the default export in the file, so you need to replace `* as theme` with `theme`

Comment: How do we change this dynamically like a toggle button change event?
Do you have any working sample?

Answer (score 3):

The theme factory is now the default export of `highcharts/themes/<theme-name>` so this will work:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import theme from 'highcharts/themes/dark-unica';
theme(Highcharts);
```

Comment: How do we change this dynamically like a toggle button change event? Do you have any working sample?

Comment: @shravan Unfortunately, it's not possible according to [this post on Highcharts forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44170). You could refresh the page and set a new theme like so:
`const chartFactory = (theme === 'darkBlue') ? darkBlue.bind(this, Highcharts) : darkGreen.bind(this, Highcharts); chartFactory();`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do this. The versions I am using are

```
"angular-highcharts": "^12.0.0",
"highcharts": "^9.3.0",
```

In your module imports you have

```
import {ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES} from "angular-highcharts";
import theme from 'highcharts/themes/dark-blue';
```

And in the providers section you have

```
{
   provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES,
   useFactory: () => [ theme ]
}
```